# Unable to start blueprint container for bundle pdi-dataservice-server-plugin due to unresolved dependencies

Tags: osgi, pentaho, kettle, blueprint-osgi

I am using windows batch file to call a Pentaho Data integration job, intermittently, the job gets hung indefinitely.

The error message in Pentaho logs is as below :

```
06:43:37,951 ERROR [BlueprintContainerImpl] Unable to start blueprint container for bundle pdi-dataservice-server-plugin due to unresolved dependencies [(objectClass=org.pentaho.metaverse.api.ILineageClient)]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$1.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:336)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am able to find some questions on similar lines, which suggest this to be a cache issue. Please help !

Comment: I think this question is not related to the `batch-file` tag in any way. I suggest you to remove such a tag...

Comment: @Aacini - I have removed it, thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to up the version of Kettle tool to 8.0.0

Here you can find the issue: 
https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-16368

Answer (score 0):

```
unresolved dependencies [(objectClass=org.pentaho.metaverse.api.ILineageClient)]
```

This means the blueprint file has a mandatory reference to a service with interface `org.pentaho.metaverse.api.ILineageClient`. The service does not seem to come up and so blueprint gives up after a timeout.

You now need to find the bundle that provides this service and determine why it does not start correctly.

Comment: @christain, I have found a temporary solution as clearing the Karaf cache and then it works to be working better. Does that give any hint about the actual root cause ?

Answer (score 0):

When your bundle is starting, it can't find this interface org.pentaho.metaverse.api.ILineageClient. So it stays in Graceperiod State.

Because it works after clearing the cache, I recommend you to:

- **1**:
  troubleshooting the bundle that expose this interface: use **diag** command from your karaf command-line to find why it can't start correctly. You can use also **headers** command to ckeck that this interface was exported
- **2**: you can put this reference as optionnal in the consumer bundle like this:

  `<reference id="give an id"
      interface="org.pentaho.metaverse.api.ILineageClient"
      availability="optional">
   </reference>`
- **3**: verify the start level of your bundle: you can handle this using start-level="..." when installing bundles in your features.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by using "call".
For example:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kettle"
call kitchen.bat -file:"C:\Elekta Projects\CE_Activities\MAIN.kjb" -level:Minimal
```

Answer (score 0):

I add the call statement, and also delete the contents of : /pentaho-server/tomcat/temp